# Problem using WHERE clause in MonetDBLite in R

Tags: r, monetdblite

I am trying to use MonetDBLite in R64bit 3.5.1.
My problem is that I can not filter the data using SQL command like this example:

```
dbGetQuery(DB,'select * from table1 where "var1" = "1"')
```

I get this error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  Unable to execute statement 'select * from table1  where "var1" = "1"'.
Server says 'ParseException:SQLparser:42000!SELECT: identifier '1' unknown'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For constant values, you need to use single quotes (`'`) or none for numeric values. So in your example,

`dbGetQuery(DB,'select * from table1 where "var1" = 1')` or

`dbGetQuery(DB,'select * from table1 where "var1" = \'1\'')` or

`dbGetQuery(DB,"select * from table1 where \"var1\" = '1'")`

should all work.

The general rule is that identifiers (`table1` or `var1`) generally only need to be quoted with `"` if they contain spaces or uppercase characters and constants (`1`) only need to be quoted with `'` if they are character strings.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  `\'` worked. what about using search parameter in where clause like : `dbGetQuery(DB, 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE "var1" = \':x\'' ,
                          param = list(x = c('1','2','3')))` . this does not return anything.